# Why is the filter for this account not working while it works for another account?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to exclude internal traffic by excluding custom ip address filter. I am using the same setup and filter pattern that I used on another account that is working. It is not working on this website however, I can still see myself in real time. So, I don't think the problem is how I set up the filter. Here is my installation code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'www.mywebsite.com');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', false);
    ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/uaEvent-V3.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: you configure GA to anonymize your IP address and then setup a filter to exclude by IP address.. well how is it supposed to exclude you by IP address if you've anonymized it?

Comment: @CrayonViolent it's set to false though, so it shouldn't be anonymizing my IP address.

Comment: huh, okay sorry, read that wrong. Okay so are you sure your current IP address matches the filter?  Can you provide details about how you actually setup the filter? Are you sure it's even you showing up in the real time report, vs. some other random person? Not sure how public/accessible your page(s) are. Do you have any other filters? Perhaps they are popping and including you before the exclude

Comment: @CrayonViolent I use the same filter setup I have on another website and that works fine over there. I am positive it is tracking me, not only in real time, but even when I submit a form, it counts it as a goal when it shouldn't be. I do have other filters. I've tried moving this filter to the top, bottom, middle, nothing works.